# Form subset of an array with special constraints

Tags: arrays, algorithm, greedy

I recently faced this problem in a coding contest:
We have to form a skill squad with members such that no member has more skill than the sum of skills of any two other member in the squad.
Given an array of skills of n members, find the maximum sum of skills of a squad possible with above constraint.
I used a greedy algorithm: 
-sort the array; 
-use three pointers and choose indices such that the sum of the first two elements (smallest) is lesser than the last (largest element) of the considered subarray. 
-Also keep moving the indices to check for all such subarrays and return the maximum sum among them.
But this passed half the cases and others failed. Can someone help me with what I am missing here? Following is my program:

```
//Author:: Satish Srinivas
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int solve(int arr[],int n)
{
    sort(arr,arr+n);

    int sum[n];
    sum[0]=arr[0];

    //precompute sums    
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum[i]=sum[i-1]+arr[i];

    }

    if(n<=2)
        return sum[n-1];

    int res=INT_MIN;

    for(int i=0;i<=n-3;i++)
    {
        int min=arr[i]+arr[i+1];

        int j=i+1;

        while(j<=n-2 && arr[j+1]<=min)
            j++;

        if(j>i+1)
        {
         if(i==0)
         {
            if(res < sum[j]-sum[0])
             res=sum[j]-sum[0];
         }
         else
         {
            if(res < sum[j]-sum[i-1])
             res=sum[j]-sum[i-1];
         }

        }

    }
  return res;
}

int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
/*
freopen("in.in", "r", stdin);
freopen("out.out", "w", stdout);
*/
int arr1[]={10,4,4,5,4};
int n1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
cout<<solve(arr1,n1)<<endl;

int arr2[]={25,60,1,5,3,35};
int n2=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
cout<<solve(arr2,n2)<<endl;

return 0;
}
//output:
//13
//120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that look a little wrong:

1. If n is equal to 2, you return INT_MIN because your for loop never executes
2. More generally, you seem to consider a team of size 2 as being invalid
3. When i is equal to 0, you want to compute the score from adding up all numbers from i to j, this is equal to sum[j] but you compute res=sum[j]-sum[0]
4. As you have sorted the array, you actually don't need to reset j in each iteration (this only matters if you are failing due to a time-out)